# Custom C++ manipulator problem

Tags: c++, stream, manipulators

I'm trying to implement my own stream manipulator inside my logging class. It's basically endline manipulator which changes state of a flag. However when I try to use it, I'll get:

```
ftypes.cpp:57: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘log->Log::debug() << log->Log::endl’
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/ostream.tcc:67: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/ostream.tcc:78: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/ostream.tcc:90: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

...

Code:

```
class Log {
public:
  ...
  std::ostream& debug() { return log(logDEBUG); }  
  std::ostream& endl(std::ostream& out);           // manipulator
  ...
private:
  ...
  std::ofstream m_logstream;
  bool          m_newLine;
  ...
}


std::ostream& Log::endl(std::ostream& out) 
{  
  out << std::endl;
  m_newLine = true;
  return out;
}

std::ostream& Log::log(const TLogLevel level)
{
  if (level > m_logLevel) return m_nullstream;

  if (m_newLine)
  {
    m_logstream << timestamp() << "|" << logLevelString(level) << "|";
    m_newLine = false;
  }
  return m_logstream;
}
```

I'm getting the error when I try to call it:

```
log->debug() << "START - object created" << log->endl;
```

(log is the pointer to Log object)

Any ideas? I suspect it's somehow connected to the fact that the manipulator is actually inside the class but that's just my wild guess...

Cheers,

Tom

EDIT: Putting this here instead of comment because of limiting formatting.
I tried to implement my streambuf and it works great with one exception: when I try to open filebuf for append it fails. Output works nicely, just append doesn't for some unknown reason. If I try to use ofstream directly with append it works. Any idea why? – 
Works:

```
std::ofstream test; 
test.open("somefile", std::ios_base::app); 
if (!test) throw LogIoEx("Cannon open file for logging"); 
test << "test" << std::endl;
```

Appends "test" correctly .

Doesn't work:

```
std::filebuf *fbuf = new std::filebuf(); 
if (!fbuf->open("somefile", std::ios_base::app)) throw LogIoEx("Cannon open file for logging");
```

Throws exception, if I set openmode to out then it works..

Cheers

Comment: In this case, because your followup question is basically completely unrelated to the original question, it'd be better to put it somewhere else, to keep things less confusing to others who might come along later on a google search or something. More importantly, it'll bring more attention to your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how manipulators work - it's all about types. What you want is something like:

```
class Log {
...
struct endl_tag { /* tag struct; no members */ };
static const struct endl_tag endl;
...
LogStream &debug() { /* somehow produce a LogStream type here */ }
}

LogStream &operator<<(LogStream &s, const struct endl_tag &) {
  s.m_newLine = true;
}
```

Note that:

1. Since m_newLine is part of `Log`, we can't be working with generic `std::ostream`s. After all, what would `std::cout << Log->endl()` mean? So you need to create a new stream type derived from `std::ostream` (I've left it out here, but assumed it's named `LogStream`).
2. `endl` doesn't actually do anything itself; all the work is in `operator<<`. The only purpose of it is to get the right `operator<<` overload to run.

That said, you're not supposed to be defining new manipulators and stream classes if you can avoid it, because it gets complex :) Can you do what you need using just `std::endl`, and wrapping an `ostream` around your own custom [`streambuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/)? That is how the C++ IO library is meant to be used.

Comment: Actually, `std::endl` in fact does work. However, it does so indirectly. First, by passing it as an argument, the right `operator<<` overload is called. This overload then in turns calls `std::endl()`

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. I can see that I was completely wrong. What I was trying to achieve was to know if the stream was flushed so that I can write the "header" in the log (time, loglevel, etc.). I was looking for some simple way to do it. So you are saying that the best way to go is write my own streambuf (NOT ostream)? Isn't it too low level for such simple thing? Cheers

Comment: The difference between `streambuf` and `ostream` is `streambuf` just gets raw, unformatted bytes, while `ostream` handles formatting without being overly concerned about how the underlying streambuf is going to get that output. I think `streambuf` is exactly where you want to be, simply because you really don't need to take any special formatting action. You just need to insert log header data after each `'\n'`, which is something that can be done at the `streambuf` level easily enough.

Comment: Ok, I tried to implement my streambuf and it works great with one exception: when I try to open filebuf for append it fails. Output works nicely, just append doesn't for some unknown reason. If I try to use ofstream directly with append it works. Any idea why?

Comment: Works:
std::ofstream test;
test.open("somefile", std::ios_base::app);
if (!test) throw LogIoEx("Cannon open file for logging");
test << "test" << std::endl;
appends "test" correctly

Doesn't work
std::filebuf *fbuf = new std::filebuf();
if (!fbuf->open("somefile", std::ios_base::app)) throw LogIoEx("Cannon open file for logging");
throws exception, if I set openmode to out then it works...

Comment: Hm, that's a mess? How did you manage to get formatted comments?

Comment: Comments only support very limited formatting - if you're going to be posting long code samples, it's best to open a new question (or if it's directly related to your existing one, edit it)

Answer (score 5):

There is defined an `operator<<(ostream &, ostream &(*)(ostream&))` but not an `operator<<(ostream &, ostream &(Log::*)(ostream&))`.  That is, the manipulator would work if it were a normal (non-member) function, but because it depends on an instance of `Log`, the normal overload wouldn't work.

To fix this problem, you may need to have `log->endl` be an instance to a helper object and, when pushed with `operator<<`, call the appropriate code.

Like so:

```
class Log {
  class ManipulationHelper {  // bad name for the class...
  public:
    typedef ostream &(Log::*ManipulatorPointer)(ostream &);

    ManipulationHelper(Log *logger, ManipulatorPointer func) :
      logger(logger),
      func(func) {
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, ManipulationHelper helper) {
        // call func on logger
        return (helper.logger)->*(helper.func)(stream);
    }

    Log *logger;
    ManipulatorPointer func;
  }

  friend class ManipulationHelper;

public:
  // ...

  ManipulationHelper endl;

private:
  // ...

  std::ostream& make_endl(std::ostream& out); // renamed
};

// ...

Log::Log(...) {
  // ...
  endl(this, make_endl) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Log
{
    public:
    class LogEndl
    {
        /*
         * A class for manipulating a stream that is associated with a log.
         */
        public:
            LogEndl(Log& p)
                :parent(p)
            {}
        private:
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,Log::LogEndl const& end);
            Log&    parent;
    };
    std::ostream& debug()   {return std::cout;}
    /*
     * You are not quite using manipulators the way they are entended.
     * But I wanted to give an example that was close to your original
     *
     * So return an object that has an operator << that knows what to do.
     * To feed back info to the Log it need to keep track of who its daddy is.
     */
    LogEndl       endl()    {return LogEndl(*this);}
    private:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,Log::LogEndl const& end);
        bool    endOfLine;

};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,Log::LogEndl const& end)
{
    // Stick stuff on the stream here.
    str << std::endl;

    // Make any notes you need in the log class here.
    end.parent.endOfLine    = true;

    return str;
};

int main()
{
    Log     log;

    /*
     * Please note the use of objects rather than pointers here
     * It may help
     */
    log.debug() << "Debug " << log.endl();
}
```

Comment: Cheers, this looks close enough but I can see I missed the point and I'd like to do it properly now :))